# How to bootstrap droplets using Terraform?

Tags: digital-ocean, devops, terraform

When creating droplets on Digital Ocean using Terraform, the created machines' passwords are sent via mail. If I get the [documentation on the Digital Ocean provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/r/droplet.html#ssh_keys) right, you can also specify the SSH IDs of of keys to use.

If I am bootstrapping a data center using Terraform, which option should I choose?

Somehow, it feels wrong to have a different password for every machine (somehow using passwords per se feels wrong), but it also feels wrong if every machine is linked to the SSH key of my user.

How do you do that? Is there a way that can be considered good (best?) practice here? Should I create an SSH key pair only for this and commit it with the Terraform files to Git as well? …?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, using passwords on instances is an absolute pain once you have an appreciable number of them. It's also less secure than SSH keys that are properly managed (kept secret). Obviously you are going to have some trouble linking the rest of your automation to some credentials that are delivered out of band to your automation tooling so if you need to actually configure these servers to do something then the password by email option is pretty much out.

I tend to use a different SSH key for each application and development stage (eg. dev, testing/staging, production) but then everything inside that combination gets the same public key put on it for ease of management. Separating it that way means if you have one key compromised you don't need to replace the public key everywhere and so minimises blast radius of this event. It also means you can rotate them independently, especially as some environments may move faster than others.

As a final word of warning, do not put your private SSH key into the same git repo as the rest of your code and definitely do not publish the private SSH key to a public repo. You will probably want to look into some secrets management such as Hashicorp's [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) if you are in a large team or at least distributing these shared private keys out of band if they need to be used by multiple people.